# I can't set TextView color in any version of android under 6.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using the android support library.  In my XML if I use TextView the text color will not change in any version of android other than android 6.0.  I have the problem on multiple screen layouts.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/ted240" />
```

If I use android.widget.TextView everything works as it should on older version of android.

```
    <android.widget.TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/ted240" />
```

I updated the support library and gradle recently.  I'm not sure if that caused the problem.  If I try changing them back I still have the same problem.

Comment: use only 6 digits of hexa number of color

Comment: Try to remove fist two FF.

Comment: First two FF indicates the opacity of that colour. Nothing wrong with it. Anyway, why do you need to use android.widget.TextView anyway?

Comment: So, does the above code work as expected if you use an earlier version of the Support Library? (i.e. 23.1.1)?

Comment: I tried going all the way back to 23 and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to clean and then rebuild the project and nothing seemed to fix it.  I tried changing it all the way back to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22'.

I seem to have fixed it by changing to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

and then once it started working again I changed to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

and everything seems fine.  I am confused but happy it works.

Comment: I believe the problem was caused by installing the Android N (API 23, N preview).

Answer (score 0):

use below six digit hexa number only not 8

```
  <TextView

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#ff0000"
   />
```

Comment: First two FF indicates the opacity of that colour. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: nothing wrong with first two FF it is indication alpha like #ARGB

Comment: i said only 6 digit allow not said to remove first two FF

Comment: I use style="@style/MyLabel" in my application.  I added android:textColor="#FFFFFF00" for testing.  Changing it to android:textColor="#ff0000" has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Support Library 23, a new getColor() method has been added to ContextCompat.

But you can use it like below method which I use,

```
public static int getColorWrapper(Context context, int id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return context.getColor(id);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

Then You need to call like below,

```
 textView.setTextColor(getColorWrapper(context,R.color.black));
```

Hope this will work for you.